# Is RegSetValueEx thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I suspect that RegSetValueEx is thread safe, but would like some confirmation from the community. If called from multiple threads, will there be any side effects?

The [RegSetValueEx MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923.aspx.aspx) doesn't mention thread safety at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Win32 Registry 'thread safe'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706336/is-the-win32-registry-thread-safe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

related Q: [Is the Win32 Registry ‘thread safe’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706336/is-the-win32-registry-thread-safe)

Comment: Thank you. The related question did provide an answer. I did search both Google and SO, but didn't come across any definitive answer.